# How to auto font like Word

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

In MS Word, if you type in Japanese, the font automatically changes to Japanese font such as MS Mincho or MS Gothic, depend on your default asian font. Then, if you type non-Japanese words, the font switches back to Calibri or whatever non-Japanese font.

However, in Excel, if you type Japanese word in a cell, the font remains non-Japanese font.
So how can I change this? I want that Excel auto changes to MS Mincho font when I type in Japanese words.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: That functionality is in Word because it is a word processor. Excel is not a word processor, it is a spreadsheet so it doesn't have that functionality. Remember software is usually designed to do a particular job well and is usually not a "jack of all trades".